# java JPopupMenu, shortcut alignment

Tags: java, swing, alignment, shortcut, jpopupmenu

Is there any way to align shortcuts of some `JPopupMenu` to the right side of the container? The default alignment is `left`.  I'm setting shortcuts like this:

```
closeItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsKOp.png

[image]

Comment: read this thread: http://www.coderanch.com/t/461743/GUI/java/JMenuItem-text-alignment-CENTER